# How to call method in button onclick event mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one method in  Inside of Razor view.

```
<div style="height: 50px; padding-left: 10%; width: 100%">
                                <b style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: xx-large">                                        
                                @functions {      
                                    public string schoolname()
                                    {
                                        if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
                                        {
                                            string currentUserName = User.Identity.Name;
                                            return GetHeaderSchoolName(currentUserName);
                                        }
                                        return string.Empty;
                                    }

                                    public string GetHeaderSchoolName(string userName)
                                    {
                                        Guid userId = SchoolBreifcase.Utilities.Common.GetUserId(userName);
                                        SchoolBreifcase.Repositories.AdminRepository adminRepository = new SchoolBreifcase.Repositories.AdminRepository();
                                        SchoolBreifcase.Models.Edmx.UserProfile userProfile = adminRepository.GetUserProfileByUserId(userId);
                                        string CurrentSchoolName = userProfile.School.SchoolName;
                                        return CurrentSchoolName + "xxx";
                                    }
                                                }
                            </div>
```

I have one button in inside of  same razor view.And I called that method(`schoolname()`) in my below button onclick event (`onclick="schoolname()"`) please see below

```
<div class="logoHeader" style="float: right; width: 15%; padding-top: 5%;">                            
                             **<button onclick="schoolname()"> xx</button>**   
                        </div>
```

But .Its Not working . My method is does not called .I have no idea for this task . You have Any idea here? and how to do solve this ?

```
Updated:
```

I know the procedure are threw  controller ,action result,get ,post, java script,jquery,etc ,all . My question is What is use of `@functions` ? in razor view . I know its helping to write server side code in inside of razor view . but i can't call this method in just one button click event . So what is the use it ? Its only used only  for  when page load .

**Finished my self :**

**See below  my Razor View  Function :**

```
<div style="height: 50px; padding-left: 10%; width: 100%">
                                    <b style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: xx-large">                                        
                                    @functions {      
                                        public string schoolname()
                                        {
                                            if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
                                            {
                                                string currentUserName = User.Identity.Name;
                                                return GetHeaderSchoolName(currentUserName);
                                            }
                                            return string.Empty;
                                        }

                                        public string GetHeaderSchoolName(string userName)
                                        {
                                            Guid userId = SchoolBreifcase.Utilities.Common.GetUserId(userName);
                                            SchoolBreifcase.Repositories.AdminRepository adminRepository = new SchoolBreifcase.Repositories.AdminRepository();
                                            SchoolBreifcase.Models.Edmx.UserProfile userProfile = adminRepository.GetUserProfileByUserId(userId);
                                            string CurrentSchoolName = userProfile.School.SchoolName;
                                            return CurrentSchoolName + "xxx";
                                        }
                                                    }
                                </div>
```

**And I am used `javascript:window.location.href="schoolname"` for call my function** .Its working now .

```
<div class="logoHeader" style="float: right; width: 15%; padding-top: 5%;">                            
                                 **<button onclick='javascript:window.location.href="schoolname"'> xx</button>**   
                            </div>
```

Thanks Guy's .

Comment: MVC is **not** WebForms. They're quite different and don't share much in common. It's a completely different way of wiring up server/client side methods. I would recommend definitely read the `getting started` guide on asp.net http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started

Comment: Thumb rule: always look at your generated html and ask yourself: if I were a browser, where is that function I'm asked to invoke? Can't see it? Then it won't work.

Comment: So I can't call that function in my button click event . right ?

Comment: No. It has to be wired to the server somehow. Please watch videos or read tutorials. MVC is such a different beast and easy to get confused.

Comment: I think i just lol'd and then watched the Crying Game 'shower scene'.

Comment: Hmm!! Are you kid me ?

Comment: Finished used myself : http://stackoverflow.com/q/16097853/2291535

Comment: Think Webforms , Write MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it completely wrong my friend because Asp.net Mvc is not like classic Asp.net Web Forms.
I suggest you take look at [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430257520) for more information.
However to solve your problem you can easily do this in CShtml :

```
@{
var result = Request["YourButtonSpecialName"];   
 }
@if (result=="xx")
{
   <div>
button clicked
</div>    
}
<div class="logoHeader" style="float: right; width: 15%; padding-top:5%;">
<form action="YOUR CURRENT PATH">
<button type="submit" name="YourButtonSpecialName" value="xx"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry your code not well. This line give lot of error's 
@functions {
var result = Request["YourButtonSpecialName"];
if (result=="xx")
{
//button clicked
}
 }

I can't use if condition . etc in razor view .. Sorry any other option here ?

Comment: Its okay .But your code was call in page load time. I want my method call only  when button clicked !!!

Comment: But my friend this is Asp.net Mvc and not Asp.net Web Forms.

Comment: Ya . Sure. I know buddy .  So i have one doubt for what use @ functions in Razor view ?

Comment: It's okay to use functions inside razor but the right way is to implement your code in controller as much as it's possible and easily you can call your Controller Actions ether with post back or even with java-script functions

Comment: I know the procedure is controller , action result,get ,etc . My question is What is use of @functions ? its helping to write server side code . but i can't call this method in just button click event . So what is the use it ?

Comment: you can only call functions defined in @functions while razor view page(cshtml file) is rendering and just inside that page.